# How to make a very simple countdown timer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, timer, logic

I'm making a simple game which generates random numbers and user has to enter a value, if users value matches the random value generated, the user wins basically this is a beginner project. I want to make a small counter so that user has a limited time to put in the value and I want that limited time to show on the screen in a label. Lets say that you have to put the value under 30 secs and the timer will count from 1 to 30 every second. The counting from 1 to 30 will update in the label every second. This is the logic I'm trying to work on right now and I can't figure out any other way... If I've done some mistake in code please comment or if you have much more simpler way please post it down below. **(pls dont vote down im at threat of account suspension)**
Heres the part of my timer code:

```
if(timer <= 30)
    {
        for(var i = 0;i >= 30;i++)
        {
            setInterval(null,1000);
            timer++;
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = timer+" seconds wasted";
        }
        alert("Time is over, you lost by "+s);
    }
```

Comment: I had created a [Timer - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/12/). You can use it as reference

Comment: If you're in danger of getting your account question-banned, it's for repeatedly asking crappy questions. Don't beg us not to downvote. Just write questions worth upvoting.  :P

Comment: @cHao I'm not any programming pro hahahha im just 13 i cant do this much :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a recursive function. 
Say `var countDown function(){ time = time--; 
setTimeout(countDown, 1000);}`

Then you need a variable time that is accessible for the countDown function. 
`var time = 30;`

In the countDown function you could create an updateTimeElement.

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval function has 2 parameters, a callback (an anomynous function in javascript thats triggered) and the milliseconds between each trigger of the interval.

What you are doing in your script is making an interval with nothing to do each second (this runs indefinately), then increment the timer integer and updating the DOM. However, this all executes within seconds.

I'd suggest (before you use a function) you look at the documentation to see how you can improve your script to work as you intent to ;-) Here are a few links that might help you get started:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

I wont be doing the work for you, since this is a good exercise for a beginner programmer ;-)

If you can't figure it out, leave a comment below this answer and I'll get back to you to help you if you need further assistance.